# Would it be considered gauche to reference my website?

Tags: discussion

I have a website which contains a list (with images) of Hugo award winners. Later, it will also contain Nebula award winners. Would it be considered crass commercialism to divulge the URL of my site, or considered OTOH an interesting tidbit?

Answer (score 9):

The [behavior](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) page suggests that if your site is part of a "good, relevant answer" to a Stack Exchange question and you disclose your association with the site, that'd be just dandy (remember to ["add context around the link" and "quote the most relevant part" of it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)). But just announcing the site without the context of answering a question would be inappropriate for the main site.

However, you're free to link it in your user profile, [mention it in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley), and consult the advertising/promotion links at the bottom of the behavior page to see if those are options you'd like to use.

Comment: Does the "good, relevant answer" rule have a loophole, in that you might be answering your own question?

Comment: @user14111 In theory, yes. But: It is unlikely that the community will consider "good" a question to which that link is the answer under any circumstance. And since it would be the *only* question this poster asked on sf&f.se, "overt self-promotion" would be claimed pretty quickly. If Clay Shannon first developed a solid reputation as a valuable sf&f.se citizen, then the "loophole" might be indulged. Maybe.

Comment: Yes, the link is there in my user profile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, then it seems to me that your profile page would be the most appropriate place for it (the profile page does contain a "website" field, after all), and I personally wouldn't see any issues with that (others with more authority than me may or may not agree).

It wouldn't be appropriate to cite it as a reference in an answer, as it wouldn't be an independently verifiable source, and mentioning it in a more ad-hoc manner doesn't seem to be in keeping with the purpose of this site either.

Comment: I do have the link in my user profile, but who looks at that?